# Cisco - BGP Best Path Algorithm - Which criteria

Tags: cisco, bgp

I set up below topology on Cisco IOU environment. R1, R2 and R3 routers are configured with one loopback interface on each, having "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2" and "3.3.3.3" addresses respectively. These loopbacks are advertised on OSPF as well as BGP processes.

[image: topology]

All three routers have full-mesh iBGP connection to each other and R1 is the route-reflector. R3's BGP table has two "2.2.2.2/32" prefix, advertised by R1 and R2, and it chooses R2's advertisement as best.

Please see R3's BGP table for 2.2.2.2/32 prefix

```
BGP routing table entry for 2.2.2.2/32, version 2
Paths: (2 available, best #2, table default, RIB-failure(17))
  Advertised to update-groups:
     1
  Local
    2.2.2.2 (metric 11) from 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 100, valid, internal
      Originator: 2.2.2.2, Cluster list: 1.1.1.1
  Local
    2.2.2.2 (metric 11) from 2.2.2.2 (2.2.2.2)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 100, valid, internal, best
```

I am a little bit confused on which BGP Best Path Algorithm criteria decides to choose R2's advertisement is best for R3.

To understand this, I tried injecting a higher MED from R2 to R3. It changed the best to the one advertised by R1. This shows that the correct criteria (without MED manipulation) is somewhere below "6-MED/Metric".

Your comments would be appreciated

Please also find the BGP configurations for R1, R2 and R3

R1

```
router bgp 5500
bgp router-id 1.1.1.1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 1.1.1.1 mask 255.255.255.255
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 remote-as 5500
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 route-reflector-client
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 remote-as 5500
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 update-source Loopback0
```

R2

```
router bgp 5500
 bgp router-id 2.2.2.2
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 2.2.2.2 mask 255.255.255.255
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 remote-as 5500
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 next-hop-self
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 remote-as 5500
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 next-hop-self
 neighbor 10.0.24.4 remote-as 777
 neighbor 10.0.28.8 remote-as 811
```

R3

```
router bgp 5500
 bgp router-id 3.3.3.3
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 3.3.3.3 mask 255.255.255.255
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 remote-as 5500
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 next-hop-self
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 remote-as 5500
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 next-hop-self
 neighbor 10.0.36.6 remote-as 777
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are seeing step 8 in the BGP best path selection process according to referenced document below.

R3 sees the IGP metric through R2 to reach 2.2.2.2 is better than through R1.

This is the metric when the link between R2 and R3 is down
[image: This is the metric when the link between R2 and R3 is down]

This is the metric when the link between R2 and R3 is up
[image: This is the metric when the link between R2 and R3 is up]

[Understanding BGP Best Path Selection Manipulation](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/network-infrastructure-documents/understanding-bgp-best-path-selection-manipulation/ta-p/3150576)